# state is not updating on click of a button

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a `boolean` `true` on the click of a button, but it shows "undefined" on `console.log`

```
export default class productdetail extends Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showCartMessage:false ,
    }
    this.handleCartListener = this.handleCartListener.bind(this);
   
   }
    handleCartListener(){
    this.setState({ showCartMessage: true });
    console.log(this.showCartMessage)
    }
    actionForProducts(product) {
      return(
         <div className="">
            <button className="add_cart btn  rounded-pill w-100  " onClick= 
                 {this.handleCartListener}>
            Add To Cart
           </button>
        </div>
      )
    }
    render(){
       return(
          <div className="p-3 h-100 ">
             {this.actionForProducts(this.props.productdetail)}
        </div>
       )
    }
}
```

How to resolve this? I tried so many times but it gives the same response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showCardMessage is a property of the state variable. Not the class instance.

```
 console.log(this.state.showCartMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

The state has been updated properly.
you have to just use `this.state.showCartMessage`, to see the changes.

you can use callback function to check the state after updating.

```
handleCartListener(){
 this.setState({ showCartMessage: true }, ()=>{console.log(this.state.showCartMessage) });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put `console.log` to check the new value of `state`. You should put it into render() because the state only has a new value when component re-render

```
render(){
  console.log(this.state.showCartMessage)
}
```

Comment: it s work for me
but in first click this give me false in console then give true

Answer (score 0):

try to work with async await i had the same probleme the value is updated but the console.log show undefined until the next click it shows the previous state. Try this :

```
 async handleCartListener(){
    await this.setState({ showCartMessage: true });
    console.log(this.showCartMessage)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use callback setState

```
handleCartListener(){
    this.setState({ showCartMessage: true },()=>{
    console.log(this.state.showCartMessage)
});
    
}
```